# converting flattened json from list into dataframe in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have a nested json file which I managed to flatten, but as a result I got a list which looks like this:

```
[{'people_gender': 'Female',
  'people_age_group': 'Young adult',
  'people_distance': 91,
  'time': 0.33},
 {'people_gender': 'Male',
  'people_age_group': 'Adult',
  'people_distance': 88,
  'time': 0.66}]
```

These are only two first instances of the list but there is of course no point of copying the whole list. Now I would like to convert it into the dataframe so the 'people_gender', 'people_age_group', 'people_distance' and 'time' are columns and in the rows are the results for respective time moments.

I simply tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(file))
```

but this just gives me the data frame with one column and in rows there are every entries for the given time moments and I don't know how to tackle it from there.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(lst)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_normalize() to get this json in